# Download summary to MS Word

Tags: r

This is what i've written for my task:

```
1:12
12:1
rep(1:2,12)
rep("Red",6)
c(rep("Red",6),rep("Blue",6))

sample(1:12,4)
sample(1:12)
sample(c(rep("Red",6),rep("Blue",6)))

alder <- data$alder
respons <- data$respons
plot(alder, respons)
behandling <- rep(c("FB2M","Placebo"), each = 15)
behandling <- factor(behandling)
data$behandling <- behandling
boxplot(respons ~ behandling, data=data)
data$randomisering <- sample(data$behandling)
boxplot(respons ~ data$randomisering, data=data)
Menn <- data[data$kjonn == 'Mann',]
table(Menn$randomisering)
```

..but when i try to file->compile report to MS Word, this is what happens:

```
Quitting from lines 3-33 (Oving3.spin.Rmd) 
Error in data$alder : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: At no point do you define the `data` object, and so R thinks you are referring to the `data()` function, which by its nature does not have subcomponents like variables.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! The error `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` usually means that you're trying to use an object in your R-session doesn't exist.

In the code above there is no dataset called `data`, thus you cannot use it.